# google map in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ipad, google-maps, mapkit

i can get current latitude and longitude from iphone sdk. but is there any google map URL
if i send current location and some text to give latitude & longitude value for that text .

Answer (score 0):

Please check with following URL to get latitude and longitude values;

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests